# Can I ignore these individuals without introducing bias?

Tags: sampling, bias, sample, selection-bias

I have a population that falls under 10 classes. Each individual may or may not come with a location - 83% overall have locations and a breakdown by class is:

| Class | # individuals | # with location | # without location | % without location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 82078 | 67977 | 14101 | 17% |
| B | 146551 | 124975 | 21576 | 15% |
| C | 115245 | 96161 | 19084 | 17% |
| D | 95194 | 84248 | 10946 | 11% |
| E | 142348 | 124015 | 18333 | 13% |
| F | 152433 | 134691 | 17742 | 12% |
| G | 85288 | 69651 | 15637 | 18% |
| H | 599851 | 472240 | 127611 | 21% |
| I | 218379 | 180745 | 37634 | 17% |
| J | 73019 | 58860 | 14159 | 19% |

I want to randomly sample the individuals for the purposes of performing a representative survey. This requires the location, so cannot use the ones without the location. By eye, there's not a drastic difference in *% without location*  across the classes (11-21%).

Is it valid to just ignore the ones without a location and proceed with a random selection of individuals as usual, assuming that those with the location are a good enough representation of the whole population?

Is there some statistical analysis / test that can be used to demonstrate this more rigorously? Would you use some kind of chi-square test maybe? Or maybe weight/stratify the classes during random selection, or use sample weights post-survey somehow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test this, but you have to ask your self whether the missingness of the location is so-called 'missing at random'. What is the outcome you are studying and can this be associated to whether you have access to an individuals location?
So you have to reflect on the invisible mechanisms behind the location being missing.

Example where you would introduce bias:
The location data is collected through a persons phone and you are studying the time people spend on social media. In this case when the location is missing, it is someone who does not own a phone and thus their time spend on social media is probably lower. The outcome is associated to the location being missing or not, so your result is biased.

Differences in percentages of missing location between classes are not necessarily a problem.

Comment: Thanks @ddb this is clear. I will have to talk with people providing the data to understand whether they are missing at random. Best,